# Migrating WordPress into https and docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, apache2, reverse-proxy

I am migrating my Wordpress site (self hosted) into another server. I changed the url to http://mynewserver.com on WP. On my new server, I run apache2 under Ubuntu, and my WP install was moved to a docker container.

I use reverse proxy in apache to direct the requests to `mynewserver.com` to the wordpress container.

In addition to that, I used Let's encrypt with certbot to implement certificates and use https. So I redirect all the http traffic to `http://mynewserver` to `https://mynewserver`.

Both the proxy and the https work well, but I am having a problem:

My site URL, as configured on WordPress, is `http://mynewserver.com` (not `https`). So, when I navigate to it, I get redirected to the `https://mynewserver.com`. The problem is, as the URL is `http`, not `https`, some of the links that come with `wp-login.php` are considered insecure by the browsers, and I don't even manage to login or display the page properly. I inspected the page returned by `wp-login.php`, and the `http` links are to my own website, so they would be redirected to the `https` version if I attempt to load them, but it seems that the browser considers them insecure and therefore do not attempt to load them.

I tried to fix this by changing my url to `https` on the database, but then `wp-login.php` keeps redirecting to itself, I have no clue why. Actually, this ends up happening with all the pages of the website.

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this?

PS - I do understand it is good praxis to post some code or configuration when asking here at SO - however, I have no clue what to copy here that could give a better picture - I'd be happy to illustrate it with a copy of my configuration files, so let me know and I will edit this question accordingly.